# Как определить название формы, с которой был сделан клик?

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

Имеется код:

```
function call() {
  var msg = $('#forma').serialize();
  $('#send').button('loading');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'file.php',
      cache: false,
      data: msg,
      success: function(data) {
        if ($(data).is("#err1")) {
          $('#send').val('Не верный формат...').addClass('btn-danger');
          setTimeout(
            function() {
              $('#send').button('reset').removeClass('btn-danger');
            }, 3000);               
        }
...
```

Этим кодом мы обрабатываем форму.

Вопрос: таких форм на странице 6 штук, как можно их обработать всё одним кодом (т.е. не копировать этот кусок кода 6 раз)? Собственно для этого, наверное, нужно определить, с какой формы был клик, но как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По клику на кнопку смотреть id формы и передавать функции call данный id.

Например:

```
button.click(function(){
Call($(this).closest("form").attr(id))
})
```

Ну и видоизменить функцию call, вместо  `var msg = $('#forma').serialize();`
написать `var msg = $(id).serialize();`.